# How to check if a value is not a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate user input to see if they enter a number and show an error if they enter anything that's not a number.

here is the html element

```
<input type="text" id="user_input">
```

here is my javascript

```
let user_input = Number(document.querySelector("#user_input").value);

if (user_input == NaN) {
    console.log("its not a number");
} else {
    console.log("its a number");
}
```

Here, when I enter a string, it still says "its a number" on the console. Why is this happening?

Comment: Use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). `NaN` is a value, doing `something == NaN` you're checking the value, not the type

Comment: `NaN == NaN` is false

Comment: and `typeof(NaN) == 'number'`. Sometime, JS puzzles me

Comment: Why not use [`<input type="number">`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number), [`.validity` and `.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#properties)?

Comment: @Cid [NaN is a set of IEEE-754 Number values](/q/2801601/4642212). This, and the `NaN !== NaN` behavior, are specified in IEEE-754, not in ECMA-262.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I know, it's just funny that *Not a Number is a number*